# Group validation

Tags: spring, validation, jakarta-ee

Is it possible to validate a bean ensuring that at least one of three fields is not null without implementing a custom validator?

So:

```
public class Foo {

    @NotNull(groups = {AtLeastOne.class})
    private Bar b1;

    @NotNull(groups = {AtLeastOne.class})
    private Bar b2;

    @NotNull(groups = {AtLeastOne.class})
    private Bar b3;
}
```

But without the groups meaning that I want to validate them all in one go. I want either b1 or b2 or b3 to be not null.

Cheers,

Comment: No HibernateValidator but yeah JSR 303.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need annotation `@Validated`. example:

```
public class Foo {

    @NotNull(groups = {AtLeastOne.class})
    private Bar b1;

    @NotNull(groups = {AtLeastTwo.class})
    private Bar b2;

    @NotNull(groups = {AtLeastThree.class})
    private Bar b3;
}
```

`@Validated(value=AtLeastOne.class)` will validate only b1
`@Validated(value=AtLeastTwo.class)` will validate only b2

**UPDATE**

```
@NotAllNull(value={"b1", "b2", "b3"})
public class Foo {

    private Bar b1;

    private Bar b2;

    private Bar b3;
}

@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = NotAllNullValidator.class)
@Target( { ElementType.TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface NotAllNull {
    String[] value;
}

public class NotAllNullValidator implements ConstraintValidator<NotAllNull, Object> {

    private String[] fields;

    @Override
    public void initialize(final NotAllNull constraintAnnotation) {
        fields = constraintAnnotation.value();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(final Object instance, final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        boolean result = false;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < fields.length; i++) {
            result |= org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.getProperty(instance, fields[i])!=null;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I don't have IDE here, there may some error in the code, but hope you can see the idea behind code

Comment: But I want to validate that Foo has a value for either b1 or b2 or b3. I don't want to validate if b1 has a value in some circumstances and b2 or b2 in others

Comment: @Ricky your question is misleading, if you need to validate all of these three, there is no method out of the box, you need to implement your validator by yourself. i will provide you the solution

Comment: I've not tested your implementation but was half way through implementing mine... they look very similar. Thank you for your  help. I guess my question was really if there was already anything out there for this. It is a bit sad that there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at @Valid and @Validated annotations on you class

Comment: I have but that's the thing... I'm already using @Validated for that kind of behaviour where I want something to be validated some times but not others. What I want here is to say that all of these fields must be validated at once and at least one of them must be not null